# createsnapshot not returning snapshot id

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating volume snapshot, using below command. In below  command (id=12686459) is the volume id

result = client['Network_Storage_Iscsi'].createSnapshot('abcd',id=12686459).

it creates snapshot and in the result it returns volumeid, which is different from snapshot id.

when I use below method to get snapshots for same volume (id=12686459)
I could see that snapshot id and volumeid (id that I got in the return result of createSnapshot api call) are different
 client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi'].getSnapshotsForVolume(id=12686459)

how to get snapshot id from return result, of the call to createSnapshot api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with the service Network_Storage_Iscsi, I reported the issue to Softlayer, but I do not when they will fix it.

You can use the Network_Storage service instead Network_Storage_Iscsi, I tested that service and the returned Id is the correct.

Regards